# Git from Jenkins pipeline is using wrong SSH private key to push back into Git repository

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm pulling a public git repo and I'm trying to use the denpal (SSH private key) credentials to push my changes back into the repo.

```
stages {
  stage('Git clone') {
    steps {
      git branch: 'feature/Jenkinsfile',
        credentialsId: 'denpal',
        url: 'git@github.com:test/denpal.git'
    }
  }
  stage('Test Git') {
    steps {
      withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'denpal', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY')]) {
        sh '''
        git commit --allow-empty -m "test withCredentials"
        git push origin feature/Jenkinsfile
        '''
      }
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately this gives the following error:

```
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials denpal
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress git@github.com:test/denpal.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/feature/Jenkinsfile^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/feature/Jenkinsfile^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision ... (refs/remotes/origin/feature/Jenkinsfile)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f ...
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git branch -D feature/Jenkinsfile # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b feature/Jenkinsfile ...
Commit message: "empty"
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test Git)
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking only exact matches of $SSH_KEY
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ git commit --allow-empty -m test withCredentials
[feature/Jenkinsfile 3ff21fc] test withCredentials
+ git push origin feature/Jenkinsfile
ERROR: Permission to test/denpal.git denied to technology-labs.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
```

I have also tried this, but this also failed:

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'denpal', keyFileVariable: 'private_key', passphraseVariable: '', usernameVariable: 'git')]){
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

The `withCredentials()` and `sshUserPrivateKey` line is writing the private key to a temporary file and assigning the location to `$SSH_KEY`, but it's not used because there is no reference to `$SSH_KEY` after that.

You can tell ssh and git about the private key file by using `$GIT_SSH_COMMAND` ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITSSHCOMMANDcode)).

Replace:

```
git push origin feature/Jenkinsfile
```

with:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i $SSH_KEY" git push origin feature/Jenkinsfile
```

Comment: Rob you absolute hero. This is perfect, tried so many things.

Answer (score 10):

A slightly fuller description of Rob's answer above, to have git checkout working with submodules on Jenkins declarative pipeline syntax.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {

        stage ('Clone') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
                withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'bitbucket_ssh', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY')]) {
                    sh 'GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i $SSH_KEY" git submodule update --init'
                }
            }
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

This is a workaround for https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-20941

Comment: ChatGPT gives me this one that's working : 


` withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'TOKEN_SSH_GITLAB', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY_PATH', usernameVariable: 'REGARDS bot')]) { sh "ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add $SSH_KEY_PATH && git <do what you want>'" }`

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to install plugins on jenkins then use the ssh-agent

https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {
agent any
stages {

    stage ('Clone') {
        steps {
            checkout scm
            sshagent(credentials: ['bitbucket_ssh']) {
                sh 'git commit --allow-empty -m "test withCredentials"'
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

}