# How does one clone a GitHub git repo with Groovy?

Tags: github, jenkins, groovy

I used to know how to do this, but that was 3 years ago.  I have this Jenkins Pipeline Groovy ...

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        
        stage("Checkout") {
             steps {
                withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'mySshUserCred', 
                  keyFileVariable: 'key_file_var', usernameVariable: 'username_var')]) {
                    sh 'git clone git@github.com:SorryAssInc/ops.git'
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

I have these parameters:

[image]

When I run my pipeline in Jenkins I get this output log:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ git clone git@github.com:SorryAssInc/ops.git
Cloning into 'ops'...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I doing wrong?  Am I missing a plugin? What is up with the `keyFileVariable: 'key_file_var'`? Is that where Jenkins will write the private key data I have stored in my Jenkins credentials or does Jenkins expect that file to exist already and if so how does one do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this steps.

```
stage('Git Clone') {
    steps {
        git branch: 'master',
            credentialsId: 'git_credential', #suggest to use credential on Jenkins.
            url: 'git_URL'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I needed here: [Git from Jenkins pipeline is using wrong SSH private key to push back into Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55476280/git-from-jenkins-pipeline-is-using-wrong-ssh-private-key-to-push-back-into-git-r)

So what I need to change what this ...

```
sh 'git clone git@github.com:SorryAssInc/ops.git'
```

... to this ...

```
sh 'GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i $key_file_var" git clone git@github.com:SorryAssInc/ops.git'
```